# How to live without transactions?

Tags: mongodb, transactions, rethinkdb, database, nosql

Most of the popular NoSQL databases (MongoDB, RethinkDB) do not support ACID transactions. They are very popular today within developers of different systems.

The problem is: how to guarantee data consistency without transactions?
I thought that data consistency is one of the main things in production. Am I wrong?
Maybe there is some technics to restore data consistency?

I would like to use RethinkDB for my project, but I'm scared about missed transactions.

Answer (score 2):

I do not know much about RethinkDB, so this answer is primarily based on MongoDB.

1. while MongoDB can not provide atomic operations on multiple documents at the same time, it does guarantee atomicity for a single operation which affects one document. That means when one query changes multiple fields of the same document, you can be sure that all these changes will be performed at the same time. Combined with the MongoDB philosophy of keeping a consistent dataset in one document instead of spreading it over many rows of different related tables, this removes many situations where you would need transactions in a relational database.
2. not *every* project needs complex transactions. Sure, there are some domains where it is essential (like most situations where you deal with money), but in other cases it isn't actually that big of a deal when some data is inconsistent for a few milliseconds. You need to consider how important data consistency is for your project. When you come to the conclusion that there are many situations where you do need transactions, then by all means, stick to SQL.
3. In a pinch, MongoDB can simulate multi-document transactions by using [the two-phase commit model](http://docs.mongodb.org/master/tutorial/perform-two-phase-commits/). It's not easy to implement, it's not easy to work with, it does not result in a pretty data model, but it is a valid workaround when you have a project which would be perfect for MongoDB in all regards except for that one use-case which just can't do without transactions.

Answer (score 1):

A lot of popular NoSQL data stores don't support atomic multi-key updates (transactions) of the box but most of them provide primitives which allow you to build ACID transactions on the application level.

If a data store supports per key linearizability and compare-and-set operation (atomic document updates) then it's enough to implement serializable client-side transactions. For example, this approach is used in [Google's Percolator](https://www.usenix.org/legacy/event/osdi10/tech/full_papers/Peng.pdf) and in [CockroachDB](https://www.cockroachlabs.com/blog/how-cockroachdb-distributes-atomic-transactions) database.

In my blog I created [step-by-step visualization of serializable cross shard client-side transactions](http://rystsov.info/2016/03/02/cross-shard-txs.html), described the major use cases and provided links to the variants of the algorithm. I hope it will help you to understand how to work with transactions with NoSQL data stores.

Among the data stores which support per key linearizability and CAS are:

- Cassandra with lightweight transactions
- Riak with consistent buckets
- RethinkDB
- ZooKeeper
- Etdc
- HBase
- DynamoDB
- MongoDB

By the way, if you're fine with Read Committed isolation level then it makes sense to take a look on [RAMP transactions](http://www.bailis.org/papers/ramp-sigmod2014.pdf) by Peter Bailis. They can be also implemented with the same set of primitives.

Answer (score 0):

In RethinkDB, you have some guanrantee for atomicity. According to the document https://rethinkdb.com/docs/architecture/

> Write atomicity is supported on a per-document basis – updates to a
>   single JSON document are guaranteed to be atomic. RethinkDB is
>   different from other NoSQL systems in that atomic document updates
>   aren’t limited to a small subset of possible operations – any
>   combination of operations that can be performed on a single document
>   is guaranteed to update the document atomically

When you want to run a non-atomic update, you have to explicitly opt in for it, according to https://www.rethinkdb.com/api/javascript/update/

> nonAtomic: if set to true, executes the update and distributes the
>   result to replicas in a non-atomic fashion. This flag is required to
>   perform non-deterministic updates, such as those that require reading
>   data from another table.

It has an issue to track some Transaction support for RethinkDB here: https://github.com/rethinkdb/rethinkdb/issues/4598

Anyway, you don't have good transaction but you have some basic guarantee that is enough for you. And try to design your operation around those basic thing.

Comment: Ah, sorry, I forget to mention that my question is connected with updates of multiple entities. In case of relations for example.